# Grpc service configuration and service method not found

Tags: .net, .net-core, grpc

I'm writing a grpc server, The default connection addresses are localhost and port 5001,
How can I change the connection port and address to configurable? In addition, when I run directly in the code, I can successfully call the service method by using the grpccurl command. However, when I double-click the console application generated by the project to run, the call again shows an error “Service 'grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection' is unimplemented.”